# PHP returning non-existent duplicate values

Tags: php, ionic-framework

I've been having a problem with displaying the contents of an array fetched via PHP from an SQL server as a JSON on ionic framework.

The array (or, at least, the output I'm getting) contains multiple duplicates of data that doesn't even exist in my database. I.e. the first 3 rows in the table are {1, 2, 3}, I will be getting something like {1, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3} or so.

Here is my .php file,

```
    <?php
   header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');        
   $data = array();
   $id      = filter_var($_REQUEST['id'], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);

   // Attempt to query database table and retrieve data  
   try {  

      $sql  = "SELECT table1.id, table1.name
                              FROM table1
                              INNER JOIN table2
                              ON table1.id= :id";
            $stmt =  $pdo->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt->execute(); 


      while($row  = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ))
      {
         // Assign each row of data to associative array
         $data[] = $row;
      }
      //while ()

      // Return data as JSON
      echo json_encode($data);
   }
   catch(PDOException $e)
   {
      echo $e->getMessage();
   }


?>
```

Here's my snippet .ts file

```
   load()
   {
       let body       : string = "id=" + this.id,
          type       : string = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
          headers    : any     = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': type}),
          options    : any     = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers }),
          url        : any     = "https://happymeal.000webhostapp.com/retrieve-foo.php";

      this.http.post(url, body, options)
      //this.http.get('https://happymeal.000webhostapp.com/retrieve-food.php')
      .map(res => res.json())
      .subscribe(data => 
      {          
         this.items = data;         
      });


   }
```

Here's a snippet of the .html file responsible for displaying data

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let item of items">

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">{{item.id}}</div>
      <div class="col">{{item.name}}</div>
      <div class="col"><button class="button" (click)="actionFunc({ record: item })">Edit Name</button></div>
    </div>
</ion-item>
```

Comment: Run your sql on a sql client. It's probably a problem with your join.

Comment: My goodness! I didn't notice 1 line was missing from the statement, silly me!